# How do I get a string from a TextBox in VS and then compare it to an integer using an if statement?

Tags: c#

Alright, I'm pretty new to C# and I'm trying to figure out how I could grab a string or a number from my TextBox in Visual Studio(Windows Form Application) and then figure out if that string is 0.

I've tried doing

```
 if(Calculations.Text == 0)
        {
           Calculations.Text = 1
        }
```

but to my avail it did not work.

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Windows.Forms;

        namespace WindowsFormsApp1
        {
            public partial class Calculatrice : Form
            {
                public Calculatrice()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }

                private void One_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if(Calculations.Text)
                    {

                    }
                }

                private void Calculatrice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

This is all I have right now I'm pretty stuck.

I want to be able to use the if statement to make comparisons with int values.

Comment: You can do this --> `string value = textbox_id.text;`

Comment: is Calculations your textbox?

Comment: You are not doing anything, where is your logic, in which you are taking input as string and comparing with 1?? I dont see any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Example:if Calculations is your textbox id,then
string input = calculations.text.tostring();
//then compare zero with " " 
if(input == "0")
{
calculations.text= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose your string in quotes before using them

```
 if(Calculations.Text.Trim () == "0")
    {
       Calculations.Text = "1";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A user can put anything in a TextBox. Use TryParse which will provide a zero even if it fails (returns false)

```
private void OPCode()
        {
            int.TryParse(Calculations.Text, out int i);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Calculations.Text = 1.ToString();
            }
        }
```